# Print CSS not working Correctly

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC3 RAZOR VB.Net App. In one of my views I am trying to create a printer friendly view using print.css . I have the following code for the view:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of xxxxxxxxxxxxx.sponsor)
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Sponsors"
End Code
@Code


Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @<p> 
    Search For: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />

    </p>


End Using

End Code

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create Sponsor", "CreateSponsor")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Exhibitor or Sponsor
    </th>
    <th>
        Sponsor Amount
    </th>
    <th>
        Contact Person
    </th>
   <th>
       Company/Organization
    </th>
   <th>
       Phone
    </th>
    <th>
       Email
    </th>
    <th>
      Paid
    </th>


    </tr>

    @For Each item In Model
    Dim currentitem = item
    @<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.status)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.amount)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.Contact_Person)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.Company_Organization)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.Phone)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentitem.Paid)
    </td>

    <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditSponsor", New With {.id = currentitem.id}) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsSponsor", New With {.id = currentitem.id}) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteSponsor", New With {.id = currentitem.id}) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Pay with Credit Card", "Credit_Card_Sponsor", New With {.id = currentitem.id})
   </td>
   </tr>

    Next
    </table>

    <div id="sidebar3">
    <p>


      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
      </p>
      </div>
```

Using the default Layout view. And the below is the print.css file

```
#header, #footer, #sidebar3, #Actions, #nav{
display: none;
}
```

Its like its not seeing the css at all when I right click in the browser and click print. The sidebar box, header image, and the menubar all show still... Any ideas????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `@media print`

```
@media only print
{
#header, #footer, #sidebar3, #Actions, #nav{
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes inside your print.css file

Comment: Why is this necessary when the print stylesheet is already limited to `media="print"`?

Comment: That was what I thought but I am very open to ideas... The print css file isn't working correctly at ALL though. Everything still shows...

Comment: I just noticed vb doesn't like the above css anyways.. It flags the upper french brace and the !. So I have changed it back to the originally posted css above..

Comment: Its better you just add it to your normal css and it works. You don't have to have seperate css with `media="print"`

Comment: It is the !important bit that is fixing your problem, not the @media bit - as you've already specified the media type in the <link> tag - so this does nothing here.

Comment: You would be correct on that....I think the bigger problem comes from my _layout view not having the media type specified for that css... And it takes precedence over this one.. It has been resolved though and thanks for all the feed back..

Answer (score 1):

The issue will be to do with the precedence of the selecters you are using and the 'cascading' nature of stylesheets.

I'm guessing you are using a different external css file for 'normal' display, via a link with no `media` specified?  This stylesheet will be overriding the print styles you defined, as if you do not specify a media type it applies to all media.

One way of fixing your issue is to use `!important` on your print rules - making the print rules have a higher precedence.

Alternatively, have a look at [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) - it gives a pretty good explanation of rule precedence, and from this you should be able to figure out why your print rules don't have higher precedence

Comment: The link is a good one but your second paragraph brought back memories from html classes in college. I overlooked that I had no media type specified on my primary css and just as you mentioned it would definitely take precedence just because it is the first style sheet it comes to... Thanks for the insight its the little things that gets me everytime...

Comment: Hopefully it brought back happy memories.  Actually, the rule that comes last wins, so the problem was probably related to specificity, unless you have some inline styles.