# printing by the css

Tags: html

When I use css for printing into a pdf for ex. content of my webpage it print more than I need like the header, footer, like of my webpage ,labels, the date ... etc which I don't want to print?!

Here is an example:

```
<html>   
  <body>   
    <img src="Snapshot_20120326.jpg"/>  
    <h1>Mezoo</h1>   
    <h2>The big member</h2>
    <button onclick="window.print();">print</button>
    <style media="print">
      h1 ,img  {  
        display: block;  
      }

      h2, button{    
        display: none;    
      }    
    </style>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're example is a little messed up, and you should probably fix it up...  But for a start, put your style sheet in the `head` not the `body`, it's not supposed to go in the body.

Comment: This might be helpful
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423392/print-css-not-working-correctly/9423423#9423423](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423392/print-css-not-working-correctly/9423423#9423423)

Comment: Rememeber to accept correct answers

Answer (score 2):

It'd probably be best to set @media print styles in a separate CSS stylesheet ...

So for example, to hide the header:

```
@media print {
.header, .hide { visibility: hidden }
}
```

You can learn more about media styling here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media tag on a link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

The print css could then turn off visibility on things you don't want to see.